# How do I Scroll parent page to top when child page is click within iframe?

Tags: iframe, scroll, parent

When someone clicks on a link within an iframe (child page), how do I get the parent page to scroll to the top? The issue is the child page will remain in the same spot of the page, because the iframe has a lot of height larger than the parent page.

Please note: the parent and child pages are on different sub domains.

I created a demo to show this:
http://www.apus.edu/_test/iframe/index.htm

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The trick is to append the following `onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"` to the `iframe` and that should do it!

Comment: Thanks! It also works if you do onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" in the body tag within the iframe.

Comment: adding onload to the iframe tag is so much sexier than adding it to the body tag, because not a lot of folks have the option to manually tag the 'body' should they use a CMS for example. Good suggestion though!

Comment: @aruanoc Works only if the domain within the iframe matches the parent domain.

Comment: Worked as a charm.

Comment: @voodoocode do you know how to do it when the domain within the iframe doesnt match the parent domain..?

Comment: @EstelleChvl I think this isn't possible due to X-Origin Policy.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I think: 1. one parent is enough, no need for parent.parent, 2. this code must be attached to the body tag of the child document within the iframe. There is no way to do it from the parent document.

Comment: And sadly it can't be a subdomain either, has to be the same domain.

Answer (score 19):

If you have cross origins (the iframe and the parent have different domains), then just calling window.scrollTo(0,0) won't work.

One solution to cross-origin is to send a trusted message from the iframe to the parent.

**Code inside the iframe:**

```
var parent_origin = 'http://your/iframe/domain/here'
parent.postMessage({'task': 'scroll_top'}, parent_origin);
```

**Then code in the parent:**

```
function handleMessage(event) {
    var accepted_origin = 'http://your/iframe/domain/here';
    if (event.origin == accepted_origin){
        if (event.data['task'] == 'scroll_top'){
           window.scrollTo(0,0);
        }
        // you can have more tasks
    } else{
        console.error('Unknown origin', event.origin);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    window.addEventListener("message", handleMessage, false);
}
```

Comment: Best answer here. Not sure you have to check event.origin though, I think browser handle this. Also, I would use a switch on `event.data.task` but that doesn't change the logic anyway.

Comment: Should parent / child origin just be the domain, or the full URL of the parent / child? i.e. should the `parent_origin` be `https://test.testsite.com`, or should it be `https://test.testsite.com/path/to/my/page.html/`, where the second URL is the URL of the parent page?

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking for a solution for a while. This worked with me. It worked when I modified var parent_origin = 'http://your/iframe/domain/here' to the URL of the parent and not the iframe  var parent_origin = 'http://your/parent/domain/here'

Answer (score 12):

Using JavaScript within the iframe, reference the parent and call the [scroll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.scroll) method.

```
window.parent.scroll(0,0);
```

(Note. This will not work if the iframe Url is a different domain than the parent.)

Comment: If embedded on a different domain this won't work due to cross origin restrictions

Answer (score 5):

Within the Iframe page.

```
window.parent.ScrollToTop(); // Scroll to top function
```

On The parrent page:

```
window.ScrollToTop = function(){
  $('html,body', window.document).animate({
    scrollTop: '0px'
  }, 'fast');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With animation

```
           window.parent.scroll({
              top: 0,
              left: 0,
              behavior: 'smooth'
            });
```