# Scroll to top of parent frame on iframe change?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Is it possible to scroll(0,0) to the top of the parent page when the user browses in an iframe? For example, we have an iframe that is the entire height of the page with search results. When you click the next page button in the iframe, the focus stays at the  bottom of the page.

I'm not even sure if it's possible to detect this. The iframe src value doesn't actually change.

P.S. I don't know why this site must use an iframe, but IE6 is the standard browser so I didn't ask questions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3125482/470749 was helpful for me. `iframe onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Actually, the onload event does appear to work when navigating within an iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com" height="2392px" width="100%" name="searchFrame" onload="scroll(0,0);"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 9):

As an alternative, you can have the iframe ask the parent frame to scroll to the top with

```
parent.scrollTo(0,0);
```

I haven't researched the official browser support for it, but it works in IE9, FF10, Chrome 17 and Safari 5.1.

Answer (score 2):

```
<iframe onload="parent.location= 'http://mysite.com/page.html#nameofdivonthetopofpage';" ...
```