# Scroll To Top On Page Load (HTML)

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have tried both `onload="window.scrollTo(0,0);"` and `onload="$('html,body').scrollTop(0);"` but after the page loads it still stays at the current position, I am using frames. I have tried some of the other suggestions but still no luck could someone please point me in the right direction. Do I need to add a scroll to top to my frame? I need the page that contains the frame to reload when the frame inside reloads, hope it makes sense.

`<body onload="window.scrollTo(0,0); $('html,body').scrollTop(0);"> 
    <iframe id="my-iframe-tag" scrolling="no"> 
    </iframe> 
 </body>`

Comment: Try :
$('#my-iframe-tag').contents().scrollTop()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hi all this seems to have done the trick `onload="parent.scrollTo(0,0);"` after some searching this helped [Scroll to top of parent frame on iframe change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972574/scroll-to-top-of-parent-frame-on-iframe-change) thanks though

Answer (score 2):

Using the [scrollTop](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) method on DOM [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Comment: Still no luck only when I refresh the page that contains the frame it jumps to the top but I want the frame containing page to jump to the top when the frame inside refreshes / loads, hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Use below code To Scroll to top, 
you can create one button and on click event you need to fire this code.**

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try that :

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  $('body').hide();
  $(window).scrollTop(0);
});
```