# Scroll page to top in jquery load function

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I tried:

```
$('#content').load("/education.php?filter_page=kurs&selected_kurs_id=" + selectedKursId + "&selected_category_id=" + selectedCategoryId  + "&kursId=" + positionKurs, function(){
     $(this).scrollTop(0);

});
```

How to scroll page up after content load?

Comment: Did you try `$('#content').scrollTop(0);`?

Comment: @31piy yes, not working too

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 'slow');
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 1000px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper"><h3>Header</h3>
```

Comment: <div id="content"  onload="scroll(0,0);"><div>

Comment: i am not sure it will work or not .Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40481874/scroll-to-top-on-page-load-html/40482005

Comment: It did not help

Answer (score 0):

Do You really need to use jQuery (for example to have an animation)?

If You do, try:

```
$('html,body').scrollTop(0);
```

OR

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
```

if you want a little animation instead of a snap to the top.

On the other hand, if You don't need jQuery simply use Javascript

```
window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord); e.g. window.scrollTo(0, 0)
```

Parameters:

x-coord is the pixel along the horizontal axis.

y-coord is the pixel along the vertical axis.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-prevent-load-scrolling-back-to-top-of-page-when-loading-new-content-into-div . It seems that scroll to top is the default behaviour. so You probably don't need the addional function inside the load method.

Comment: You could also try `$(document).scrollTop(0);`

Answer (score 0):

It's my experience that you need to delay the scrolling after loading or it won't do anything.
Try this:

```
$('#content').load("/education.php?filter_page=kurs&selected_kurs_id=" + selectedKursId + "&selected_category_id=" + selectedCategoryId  + "&kursId=" + positionKurs, function(){
     settimeout(function()
     {
         $('#content').scrollTop(0);
     }, 100);

});
```

Comment: Try setting a bigger timeout, like 1000

Answer (score 0):

Try the same .load as you posted:

```
$('#content').load("/education.php?filter_page=kurs&selected_kurs_id=" + selectedKursId + "&selected_category_id=" + selectedCategoryId  + "&kursId=" + positionKurs);
```

**BUT**

Inside *education.php* add:

```
<script>
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
</script>
```