# move to top of page when changing iframe content without using JavaScript

Tags: html, iframe

I have checked the questions:
[How do I Scroll parent page to top when child page is click within iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064873/how-do-i-scroll-parent-page-to-top-when-child-page-is-click-within-iframe)
and
[Scrolling parent page when remote content loads in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411848/scrolling-parent-page-when-remote-content-loads-in-iframe)
But I would like to avoid javascript if possible.
I have an iframe

```
<iframe name="MapFrame" id="MapFrameID" src="http://maps.google.ch/maps?f=q&..."></iframe>
```

And some links that point to it:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=St%C3%A4mpflistr.+28,+3052+Zollikofen..." target="MapFrame">mostra sulla mappa</a>
```

My problem is that some of the links are far below in the page and when they are "clicked" the iframe is not visible or only partially visible.

How can I force the page to scroll to the top without using javascript?

I already have a div at the top of the page with id=Fascione that I use in my footer to "go to the top"

```
<a href="#Fascione"><img class="NoBackground" alt="Go to top" src="images/common/go_up_black.png" width="30" height="30"></a>
```

and I would like to re-use it; is this possible (again without javascript)?

Comment: I don't think there is a way without js, why not use js?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try this piece of code:

`<a href="#Fascione" onclick="parent.scrollTo(0,0);">Go to the top</a>`

This is a easy way to scroll the page to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to use Javascript, which isn't that hard. Here's what to change:

```
<a href="#Fascione" onclick="var map = document.getElementById('MapFrameID'); map.src = 'http://maps.gooogle.com/maps...'">mostra sulla mappa</a>
```

The href="#Fascione" will push the page to the top, and changing the SRC on the iframe will automatically trigger the update.

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible without javascript.