# anchor with changing iframe content

Tags: iframe, anchor

I tried to comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11141950/move-to-top-of-page-when-changing-iframe-content/11142162#11142162) for clarification to what I might need but without enough rep I can't so here we go...

I want change the content of an iframe while targeting an anchor tag to scroll to a certain point lower on the page.

I tried to implement the js on the other page but while it scrolled ok, the iframe content did not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
<html>
  <body>
    The frame:
    <iframe id="theFrame" src="about:blank" width="90%" height="600"></iframe>
    <br />
    The link: <a href="#bottomOfPage" onclick="document.getElementById('theFrame').src='http://www.bing.com/';">change frame and scroll to bottom</a>
    <br />
    <div style="height:600px;background:#8cc">padding...</div>
    Bottom of page.
    <div id="bottomOfPage"><div><!--this is the marker-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This seems to have hit the spot thanks! (It also helped me realize another error I had so double thanks!)