# How do I Scroll parent page to top when child page is clicked within iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll, parent, reload

I have the same problem than **Evan** here :

[How do I Scroll parent page to top when child page is click within iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064873/how-do-i-scroll-parent-page-to-top-when-child-page-is-click-within-iframe)

But my iFrame and parent page don't have the same domain. So the browser does not allow this :

```
onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"
```

Oh, and I have no access to the parent's code at all. any idea..?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have page from d1.com as parent and d2.com in iframe.

What you need is open invisible iframe inside iframe (url should be like d1.com/scrollUp.html) with code

```
onload="window.parent.parent.scrollTo(0,0)"
```

Comment: I just edited. I have no access to the parent page / code .

Comment: Is there any anchors on parent page?
If we have ankor  <a name="top"></a> on top of parent page, we can set parent page url to something like  d1.com/myPage.htm#top. It  should be the same page with hashtag. Changing hashtag will not reload page but will scroll it to anchor.

Comment: nothing at all.. I found a working exemple : https://jsfiddle.net/makcnrda/ but can't figure out how it works :(