# How do I forbid an iFrame from scrolling its parent window?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an HTML document which, towards its bottom, contains an iframe.

In this case, the iframe embeds a Google Spreadsheet, with the code:

```html
<iframe id="gsheet-group" width="100%" height="400" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<!----DOCUMENT_KEY----->/edit?usp=sharing&rm=minimal&gid=0&single=true&widget=false&chrome=false&headers=false">Loading sheet..</iframe>
```

I believe that this iframe contains some javascript that causes its [parent window to scroll to the top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3064873/how-do-i-scroll-parent-page-to-top-when-child-page-is-click-within-iframe) on certain events, such as when its loading is complete or its content is navigated in certain ways.  (This behaviour persists if the iframe is embedded within a second iframe.)

If I can't directly modify the source code of the iframe, can I prevent a parent window from being manipulated by javascript in iframe-embedded content?

### What I've tried

I'm grateful to the commenters for suggestions, none of which have sadly solved the problem:

- Adding `sandbox="allow-scripts allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-same-origin"`  to the `<iframe>` element (to remove `allow-top-navigation`; @CBroe).
- Overriding `window.scrollTo` (@Ryano)
- Putting the iframe in a separate iframe (@Ryano)

Comment: "_this iframe contains some javascript ..._" Remove the script?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to edit the content of an iframe?

Comment: Why not? If the iframe can manipulate the parent, you can manipulate the iframe.

Comment: *"I believe that this iframe contains some javascript that causes its parent to scroll to the top on certain events..."* Not unless your page is served from the same origin as the iframe's source. If it's cross-origin (as seems likely), the iframe doesn't have access to scroll the parent window, more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_script_api_access

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This was what I'd understood, yet the scrolling occurs only when I include the iframe.  Could a mechanism other than JavaScript be responsible?

Comment: @MartinSmith No idea I'm afraid. :-)

Comment: Is it manipulating the URL hash of the parent document maybe ...? That could cause a "jump", or also smooth scrolling if the parent page had the latter enabled - and is not restricted by the Same Origin Policy, write access to the parent's location is allowed. In that case, sandboxing the iframe to remove `allow-top-navigation` might help.

Comment: i agree with @Cbroe, and if that doesn't work maybe try overriding window.scrollTo on your page? or add some css to make your page not scrollable? or get really dirty and put the iframe inside another iframe? whatever fits :)

Comment: Creative ideas! Alas, I need the page to be scrollable by the user; and overriding window.scrollTo and putting iframe-in-iframe have no effect.

Comment: No time to check right now, but IIRC scrollIntoView will make your parent page scroll even when called from inside a cross-origin iframe. Not sure how you could prevent that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One such API that would allow even cross-origin iframes to scroll the top document is [`Element#scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView). I didn't check it's really what your embedded page was doing, but that sounds like a very plausible explanation.

Here is a minimal example. To reproduce:

- Run the snippet
- Immediately scroll to the top of the page manually.
- Wait about 2s for the snippet scrolls back to view automagically:

(You can also click in the result iframe to call scrollIntoView again, 2s later).

```js
onclick = e => setTimeout(() => {
  document.body.scrollIntoView();
}, 2000);
onclick();
```

```html
Scroll to the top of the top page and wait 2s.
```

After digging the specs I'm afraid there is no out-of-the-box solution to prevent this behavior...
One noticeable thing though is that [Chrome will not scroll to fixed elements in an iframe](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1019427#c_ts1598605695). This means that we can actually hack-around this *bug* to define a "scroll-stop" layer: You can wrap the target iframe in an other iframe, set this inner iframe's position to fixed and so that it covers entirely the wrapping iframe. This will prevent Chrome from scrolling this iframe's ancestors:

```css
iframe { position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; border: none; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
```

```html
<iframe srcdoc="
<script>
  onclick = e => setTimeout(() => {
    document.querySelector('h1').scrollIntoView();
  }, 2000);
  onclick();
</script>
<h1 style='margin-top: 100vh' >I still scroll into view, but not the top page.</h1>
"></iframe>
```

However this is a complete hack-around, it's basically a bug exploit, it obviously doesn't work in other web-browsers and it may even fail in a future version of Chrome, if they fix the issue.
But that's the only thing I could find for now.

What I invite you to do though is to make your point over at [W3C's CSS working group's Github repo](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/new) so that they consider adding a property that would allow this feature officially.

Comment: In my case the window is scrolling to the top, rather than the position of the iframe,   but I'd not be surprised if the cause is analogous to the behaviour you've described.  I've opened an [issue at W3C](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/7134); please do contribute, especially if I've misunderstood your point!

Answer (score 2):

After following @Kaiido's advice to follow this up at W3C, comments there have confirmed that the desired behaviour is indeed not supported by current standards.  If accepted, a [proposal](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/blob/main/policies/vertical_scroll.md) will allow vertical scrolling to be disabled via:

```html
<iframe src="..." allow="vertical-scroll 'none'"></iframe>
```

The status of the proposal can be tracked [here](https://github.com/w3c/webappsec-permissions-policy/issues/171).

Comment: (The "will" is a big strong here ;-) The issue hasn't received much update in the last 4 years. Hopefully your issue will get things on track again.)