# prevent iframe scroll to the bottom of parent document

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I have an `iframe` in the footer of the page. When I load the page it scrolls to the **bottom**.

**What I have tried:**

- I tried `loading="lazy"` to make the `iframe` load when the user scrolls down but it triggers too early and jumps down to the iframe which confuses the user.
- I have tried `onload` attribute to scroll up when `iframe` is loaded but it gives me the ugly effect of scrolling down first and then up because the iframes take **3 sec to load**.
- I also tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15793882/15113491) without any success:

```js
window.onload = function() {
    // blur the iframe
    document.getElementById("bing").blur();
    // set focus on #foo
    document.getElementById("foo").focus();
    // when iframe tries to focus, focus #foo
    document.getElementById("foo").onblur = function() {
        this.focus();
    };
};
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="text" value="foo" /><br />
<iframe id="bing" width="800" height="500" src="http://wwww.bing.com" />
```

- I have also tried the `sandbox` attribute mention in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70940758/15113491) but it dosen't work for my case.

Do you have any suggestions on preventing the `iframe` from stealing the focus and scrolling the user down?

Comment: Setting `sandbox` attribute into `iframe` tag [works](https://jsfiddle.net/mdrf1sw4/1/) for me.